# Decimal to Binary function, Python

Tags: python

I am trying to created a function that takes in a Decimal represented value and converts it into Binary represented value.

Assuming the argument is always an integer:

```
import math

def binary_decimal_converter(x):

    binary_representation = 0
    number = x

    while number != 0:
        n = 1
        while x not in range(n,n*2):
            n *= 2
        binary_representation += 10**(int(math.log(n,2)))
        number -= n

    return binary_representation
```

**The problem:**

If x is in the list below, the program runs normally.

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128....]
```

But if any other number is used, the program gets stuck in an unbreakable loop.

Why the loop:

```
while number != 0: #line 24
```

cannot run twice?

Comment: Can `number` be `0` if `x=3`?

Comment: Unless this is homework, why not just `bin(x)[2:]` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang supposedly, yes.
The first time `n = 2` and `number -= 2`.
The second time `n = 1` and `number -= 1`.
Then `number == 0`

Comment: @JohnColeman It is a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `number = x` and then using both:

```
import math

def binary_decimal_converter(x):
    binary_representation = 0
    number = x

    while number != 0:
        n = 1
        while x not in range(n,n*2): # CHANGE x TO number
            n *= 2
        binary_representation += 10**(int(math.log(n,2)))
        number -= n

    return binary_representation
```

If you change `x` to `number` on the specified line, it works. `x` is not being updated, `number` is.